# Let $\sigma$ be the $m$-cycle (1 2 $\ldots m)$. Prove that $\sigma ^i$ is also an $m$-cycle if and only if $i$ is relatively prime to $m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups, permutations

I have consulted some other sources, and think that I have some handle on the basic ideas behind the proof, but am having trouble articulating them.

I understand that $\sigma$ sends $a_k$ to $a_{k} + 1$ (mod m). Moreover, $\sigma (a_k +1) = a_k +2$ (mod m) That is to say $\sigma ^2 $ sends $a_k$ to $a_k + 2$. One can repeat this indefinitely and can easily show that for any $i \in \mathbb{Z}$$ \sigma^i (a_k) = a_k +i$ (mod m)

Is this the right direction or am I dead wrong?

Comment: are you convinced that you have showed that $\sigma^i$ is an $m$ cycle?

Comment: It suffices to show that $(\sigma^{i})^{lcm(i,m)/i} = 1$. Why?

Comment: To Praphulla, the question is to prove that $\sigma^i$ is an m-cycle iff i is relatively prime to m.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It might help if you consider a simple example, such as the powers of the circular permutation $\sigma=(1,2,3,4,5,6)$.  You'll see that $\sigma^2=(1,3,5)(2,4,6)$ consists of two disjoint 3-cycles, and that $\sigma^3$ consists of three disjoint 2-cycles.

Suppose $\sigma=(1,2,\ldots,m)$. Then $\sigma^i$ maps $k$ to $k+i$ for every $k$ (where sum is modulo $m$), hence maps $k+i$ to $k+2i$, $k+2i$ to $k+3i$, and so on.  Thus $\sigma^i: k \mapsto k+i \mapsto k+2i \mapsto \cdots k+(m-1)i \mapsto k$.  These elements are distinct (i.e. $\sigma^i$ is an $m$-cycle) iff $k+ix$ and $k+iy$ are distinct whenever $x$ and $y$ are distinct, i.e. iff $k+ix \not\equiv k+iy$, for all distinct $x,y \in \{0,1,\ldots,m-1\}$, i.e. iff  $i(x-y) \not\equiv 0 \pmod m$. Show that this condition is satisfied iff $i$ and $m$ are relatively prime.

Comment: How to show $i(x-y)\not\equiv 0 (mod m)\iff gcd(i,m)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

We know that if $|\sigma|=k$, then $|\sigma^m|=k/(k,m)$.

Furthermore $(k,m)=1$ if and only if $k = k/(k,m) = |\sigma^m|.$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sorry, i change the letters from your problem, but that is the same idea